what is the stringy stuff growing off this plant?

i noticed stringy stuff off a plant I have and am concerned its some sort of mold ... its very fine like a cobweb whitish in color and whispy. it is not sticky like a spider web and i dont see any mites or anything on the plant. the plant is not very healthy been trying to get it to grow better below is another strand

the white stuff also clings and grows on a zip tie I put around the plant to get it to grow in a slightly more verticle direction. it is also strange there seems to be a sticky coating on the zip ties and also on the pot ... possibly something the plant is dropping?

and if someone could help me identify the plant that would be awesome! below is one of its leaves and another tiny hair as well.


I really want the plant to do well i found it in a pot on the side of the road with a bunch of free stuff and its never been that healthy but I have been trying and its new leaf growth looks healthy but they then wilt and die back after a while.
and a picture of the full plant


Hello, and welcome to the site.  Could you please give us a picture of the whole plant from a little further back to help with identification?

done new pic of full plant

I cannot identify a cause for what you see.  It could be adventitious roots or it could be a pest like a spider mite or even harmless spiders. This plant looks like Heptapleurum arboricola also known as the Hawaiian schefflera and is etiolated and stretched out from low light. It needs a reset. Here are my recommendations:

cut it back so the stems are about six inches (12 cm) from the soil
increase the amount of light
decrease water until you see new growth
spray it with dish soap and water at five ml soap to one liter of water. Repeat three times at five to six day intervals. Wash the soap off with a spray after a few minutes.

If the problem is the pest then the soap and water will deal with it.  If these are hair roots due to high humidity or spiders then no further action is needed.

Oh awesome! I am going to stick it near the grow light again i moved it away incase they were a fungus. Is a 20W LED grow light enough?

@CcDd A 20W light is a start but more light is better, an unobstructed southern exposure is best
